# Modal Dialogs and Minimal Download Strategy

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, modal-dialog, minimal-download-strategy, mds

I am having the following issue in SharePoint 2013 Online (Office 365 Preview): when I try to display in a modal dialog a page that relies on MDS (Minimal Download Strategy), the dialog opens but then closes immediately.

Is this a known issue, and how can I fix this?

To be more specific:

- I am using `SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog` to open the dialog
- MDS pages are pages whose url contains `/_layouts/15/start.aspx#`

When I remove the MDS part from the url the dialog works fine.

[Edit] To clarify, I am talking about having the mds page inside the dialog, not calling the dialog from a mds page. Something like this:

```
SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog({url:'/someSite/_layouts/15/start.aspx#/SitePages/Home.aspx'})
```

Comment: Does this happen with every location you try to open with `showModalDialog`?

Comment: @JamesLove it only happens with the mds ones. If I remove the /_layouts/15/start.aspx# it works fine.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce your issue. Being on page `/_layouts/14/start.aspx#/SitePages/Home.aspx`, I run `SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog({url:'/_layouts/settings.aspx'})` from IE developer tools and the dialog shows just fine. The portal is Office365 E3. Can you provide more details?

Comment: @AndreyMarkeev in your example /_layouts/settings.aspx is not a mds page. Try SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog({url:some_mds_url})

Comment: @AndreyMarkeev btw your example should be /15/ and not /14/, right?

Comment: 15, yes, sorry, wrote it by hand. Aha, so you're trying to pass page in mds format as the target for the dialog. I thought the problem was that you was not able to launch any dialog **from** mds page. Ok, now that's clear and I have one question: why do you want it? In most cases this will neither improve performance nor decrease traffic. Mds starts yielding profit only then you navigate between mds pages. In this case, the contents of the other page is loaded asynchronously. But usually you don't jump through pages within a dialog (maybe except for a wizard).

Comment: @AndreyMarkeev good point, but in some cases 1/ the same pages can be used in modal and as standalone, and switching between modes adds complexity 2/ a modal dialog can be opened in full screen and serve as the startpoint for a new navigation. I have both scenarios in my implementations.

Comment: I have a question: with MDS enabled simply accessing the site's link should already re-build the "MDS layout based link", I'm wondering if you tried (particularly that you state - "start-point for navigation").

Comment: @C.Marius-MVP sorry, I don't get your comment, and what you mean by "simply accessing the site's link". Could you please elaborate?

Comment: @Christophe The MDS load the difference between your current page and the new one, and it uses a js to apply the difference. In my opinion that when you call the content of your modal dialog the js script applies the differences but it doesn't run the js that opens the modal dialog. So, I have two question. Is the dialog's html updated (but hidden)? Have you tried to run the show dialog after the MDS load is completed (using a js debugger)?

Comment: Christophe, any luck resolving this?

Comment: @RobertKaucher no luck, I just had the issue again today!

Answer (score 2):

Do you wait for the SP-JS Libraries to be fully loaded? I had a few different problems with JavaScript code and confusing behaviour. You can simply add this code to your page where you open the modal dialog. "modaldialog" is the name of the function to be executed after everything has been loaded.

```
_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("modaldialog");

function modaldialog(){
  SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog({url:'/someSite/_layouts/15/start.aspx#/SitePages/Home.aspx'});
}
```

Comment: The dialog works fine with non-MDS pages. Have you actually tested your code successfully?

Answer (score 0):

I faced issue of a similar kind. I went and gave a quick study to MDS and came out with my understanding that MDS is a loading mechanism which loads the requested page async and only the difference of the page. Now when we launch a modal dialog box it get initiated from the beginning and has a blank html. So the MDS loading does not make sense here as the difference between the pages are 100% and in this case if you provide the MDS relative URL the Ajax Delta manager throws up the error saying that it is returning some value that is undefined. 
So loading something in a modal Dialog with MDS relative URL is not valid according to my understanding.

Thanks and Regards

Comment: The first time, MDS should load the whole page. It's only on the subsequent loads that the difference is loaded.

Comment: Thanks Christophe for clarification. But I am still confused because for MDS to work the download manager tries to find the difference between the start.aspx and the requested page. Since we cannot provide the MDS enabled site URL containing "/../_layouts/start.aspx#/_layouts" we cannot have that working in Modal Dialog right?

Comment: sorry, I don't understand what you mean with "/../_layouts/start.aspx#/_layouts". In my example, I am calling "/_layouts/15/start.aspx#/SitePages/Home.aspx".

Comment: Ooh..is it working fine when you are opening page -"/_layouts/15/start.aspx#/SitePages/Home.aspx" in your modal dialog.. as I got Ajax Delta manager error.

Answer (score -2):

I had a similar issue and found that SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog no longer works in SP13. See the article below:

[SP UI ModalDialog do not work in SharePoint 2013](http://www.enjoysharepoint.com/Articles/Details/sp-ui-modaldialog-showmodaldialog-do-not-work-20572.aspx#)

Comment: Please add more details from the link to your post, the answer is not very helpful as of now

Comment: And it works well in 2013, you just need to make sure the SP.UI.Dialog.js is properly loaded before you execute the call..

Comment: As your posted link actually states! The problem OP is having is related to opening an MDS style link in a modal dialog, not opening an actual modal

Comment: @RobertLindgren not sure what you mean by "actual modal", I consider my use case an actual modal dialog! I agree that it is different from what this answer describes, and I disagree with the statement that SP UI ModalDialog doesn't work in SP 2013.

Comment: @Christophe, that's what I meant, that you had no problem opening a modal, but open one with the MDS-style URL :)

Comment: We're on the same page :-) To be more specific (cf. my question) the dialog box actually opens, but it doesn't stay.